# jQuery sortable initial load menu order not correct

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a sequence in my database that stores numbers like so:

**3, 7, 9, 11, 15**

I pull this sequence from my database and try sort the menu based on this sequence.

**My divs are like so:**

```
<div id="menu_left">
    <div id="item_box_3">3</div>
    <div id="item_box_7">7</div>
    <div id="item_box_9">9</div>
    <div id="item_box_11">11</div>
    <div id="item_box_15">15</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery is the following: 'data' is: 3, 7, 9, 11, 15 - this is then split into an array.

```
var orderArray = data.split(',');
var listItems = $("#menu_left"), items = $("#menu_left > div");

for (var i = orderArray[orderArray.length - 1]; i >= 0; i--) {
    listItems.prepend(items.get(orderArray[i] - 1));
}
```

My sortable is saving completely fine, but when I retrieve this data value (3,7,9,11,15) it seems to not work. When I have (1 to 15 (15 items)) it works fine, which got me thinking is it because it thinks some items are missing?

Any ideas?

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ocrwp81b/

Comment: Your loop goes from 11 down to zero by one. Is that what you want? I don't understand what you're trying to actually do, or see how jQuery and jQuery UI are relevant to your question.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. I'm trying to basically order the divs based on the sequence I get from the database. So I have '3,7,9,11,15' and on the divs, there's IDs and I want to order the divs by the ID sequence from the database.

Comment: So like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t7hbbvya/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code and tell if this is the behavior you were looking for.

```
var orderArray = ["3","9","7","15","11"];
var listItems = $("#menu_left"), items = $("#menu_left > div");

for (var i = orderArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    listItems.prepend($("#item_box_"+orderArray[i]));
}
```